# Laravel: Trouble with update db after click button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem: I build an app and I have 2 tables in my db: *habits* and *users*. The *User* has a field called *points* and after click a button *'Add point'* I want to increment that value. I added a method in *HabitsController* called *addPoints* and button in a view, but I get an error message: *MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message*. There is my code.

HabitsController.php

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Habit;
use App\User;
use DB;
use App\Quotation;

class HabitsController extends Controller
{
     /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
       //store in $habits all posts of current user 
        $habits = DB::table('habits')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('habits.index')->with('habits', $habits);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('habits.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'difficulty'=>'required'
        ]);

        $habit = new Habit;
        $habit->name = $request->input('name');
        $habit->description = $request->input('description');
        $habit->difficulty = $request->input('difficulty');
        $habit->NumberOfCompleted = 0;
        $habit->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $habit->save();

        return redirect('/habits')->with('success', 'Habit created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $single = Habit::find($id);
        return view('habits.show')->with('single', $single);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $single = Habit::find($id);
        return view('habits.edit')->with('single', $single);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name'=>'required',
            'description'=>'required',
            'difficulty'=>'required'
        ]);

        $habit = Habit::find($id);
        $habit->name = $request->input('name');
        $habit->description = $request->input('description');
        $habit->difficulty = $request->input('difficulty');
        $habit->NumberOfCompleted = 0;
        $habit->save();

        return redirect('/habits')->with('success', 'Habit created');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $single = Habit::find($id);
        $single->delete();

        return redirect('/habits')->with('success', 'Habit deleted');
    }

    public function addPoint(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $habit = User::find($id);
        $habit->points += 1;
        $habit->save();

        return redirect('/habits')->with('success', 'Habit created');
    }
}
```

show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')
<div class="row single">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 showSingleHabit">
        <h2>{{$single->name}}</h2>
        <p>{{$single->description}}</p>
        <p>{{$single->difficulty}}</p>
        <p>{{$single->NumberOfCompleted}}</p>
        <a href="/habits/{{$single->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a>

        {!!Form::open(['action' => ['HabitsController@destroy', $single->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'DELETE')}}
            {{Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger'])}}
        {!!Form::close()!!}

         {!!Form::open(['action' => ['HabitsController@update', $single->id], 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
            {{Form::hidden('_method', 'POST')}}
            {{Form::submit('Add point', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!!Form::close()!!}
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::resource('habits', 'HabitsController');
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

I will be grateful for any help. :)

Comment: You have to change method to PUT. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'POST')}}
```

To

```
{{Form::hidden('_method', 'PUT')}}
```

Comment: There is no error now, but my method don't increment points value. Do you have some idea what is wrong in controller method addPoint?

Comment: whats the thing you want to increment? @Morgan

Comment: The value called points in my users db table for current user.

Comment: if its points, then you should change HabitsController@update to  HabitsController@addPoint

Comment: now I get error 'Action App\Http\Controllers\HabitsController@addPoint not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\happ\resources\views\habits\show.blade.php)'

Comment: you need to add route for that, add this to your ٌRoutes    Route::put('habits/add-point', 'HabitsController@addPoint '); and i think this will do